# Discord.JS v14 SlashCommandBuilder Subcommand Function is giving an err

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I created a command using the `SlashCommandBuilder` class in discord.js v14 but when I try to add a Subcommand I get this error. If anyone has any information it would be nice.

My Code:

```js
.addSubcommand(subcommand => {
    subcommand
        .setName("channel")
        .setDescription("Sets the channel to send earthquake logs.")
        .addChannelOption(option => {
            option
                .setName("channel")
                .setDescription("Channel to send earthquake logs.")
                .setRequired(true)
        })
})
```

I'm trying to add subcommand but it gives me this err

```
/Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:41 
  throw this.error; 

ExpectedValidationError: Expected 
  at InstanceValidator.handle (/Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:714:75) 
  at InstanceValidator.parse (/Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:201:88) 
  at assertReturnOfBuilder (/Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:942:53) 
  at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (/Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1347:51 
  at MixedClass.addChannelOption (/Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1323:171 
  at /Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/src/commands/deprem.js:20:26 
  at MixedClass.addSubcommand (/Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1362:501 
  at /Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/src/commands/deprem.js:14:18 
  at MixedClass.addSubcommandGroup (/Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1441:501 
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yscnpkr/Desktop/mira v2/src/commands/deprem.js:8:101 { 
 validator: 's.instance(V)', 
 given: undefined, 
 expected: [Function: SlashCommandChannelOption]
```

Error:
[image: Console Error is here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the error it says `expected: [Function: SlashCommandChannelOption]` but `given: undefined`. It means it expected an instance of `SlashCommandChannelOption` but received `undefined`.

If you check your callback functions, you can see that you don't return anything. If there is no explicit `return` statement, the function automatically returns `undefined`.

So, all you need to do is to return options:

```js
.addSubcommand((subcommand) => {
  return subcommand
    .setName('channel')
    .setDescription('Sets the channel to send earthquake logs.')
    .addChannelOption((option) => {
      return option
        .setName('channel')
        .setDescription('Channel to send earthquake logs.')
        .setRequired(true);
    });
});
```

As you're using arrow functions, you could also just get rid of the curly brackets and the `return` keyword:

```js
.addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
  subcommand
    .setName('channel')
    .setDescription('Sets the channel to send earthquake logs.')
    .addChannelOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('channel')
        .setDescription('Channel to send earthquake logs.')
        .setRequired(true),
    ),
);
```